# Programmatically create a shortcut to the recycle bin or other special folders

Tags: c#, windows-shell, shortcut-file

I'm trying to make a console app that will create shortcut of Recycle bin.

My code:

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
object shDesktop = (object)"Desktop";
WshShell shell = new WshShell();
string shortcutAddress = (string)shell.SpecialFolders.Item(ref shDesktop) + @"\Recycle Bin.lnk";
IWshShortcut shortcut = (IWshShortcut)shell.CreateShortcut(shortcutAddress);
shortcut.Description = "New shortcut for Recycle Bin";
shortcut.Hotkey = "Ctrl+Shift+N";
shortcut.IconLocation = @"C:\WINDOWS\System32\imageres.dll";
shortcut.TargetPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System) + @"\Recycle.Bin";
shortcut.Save();
```

It Creates a "Shortcut" but it's not usable at all. A message pops up when. I try to open it which produces:

> "Windows is searching for recycle.bin. To locate your file yourself click browse."

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow. Please remoe the [thanks in advance](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it) part.

Comment: So what makes you think the recycle bin is a standalone file called `Recycle.Bin`? You know there's a setting in Windows to display the Recycle Bin on the desktop?

Comment: I already have my Recycle Bin visible but what's your point?Maybe i misunderstood your answer..

Comment: I certainly didnt think that c:\windows\system32\recycle.bin was the right path, I thought it was always the root of the drives and called $recycle.bin

Comment: That wasn't an answer, it was a question. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I tried to but when i change my path i got this exception: {"Value does not fall within the expected range."}

                                      shortcut.TargetPath =                   Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System) + @"C:\$Recycle.Bin";

Comment: I'm trying to make a console app that will create shortcut of Recycle bin.

Comment: Yes, that part is clear from your question ... I'm asking why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify the special CLSID of the Recycle Bin as `TargetPath`:

```
IWshShortcut shortcut = (IWshShortcut)shell.CreateShortcut(shortcutAddress);
shortcut.TargetPath = "::{645ff040-5081-101b-9f08-00aa002f954e}";
shortcut.Save();
```

There's also no need to specify `IconLocation`. The appropriate Icon is chosen automatically in the case of special folders.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create a shortcut that opens special folders, you need to create a shortcut to explorer.exe and [pass the appropriate GUID](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3123-clsid-key-guid-shortcuts-list-windows-10-a.html) prefixed with a double colon as argument:

```
string explorerExePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows), "explorer.exe");
shortcut.TargetPath = explorerExePath;
shortcut.Arguments = "::{645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}";
```

You don't even need to provide the explorer.exe as target, you can target the GUID directly:

```
shortcut.TargetPath = "::{645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}";
```

Alternatively, you can just [enable the display of the Recycle Bin on the desktop instead](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/15057/windows-show-hide-recycle-bin).

Comment: There's actually no need to use a link to explorer exe. You can use the special CLSID directly as `TargetPath`. See my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate much appreciated!